# UTF8 and T61 strings, how do I see what my SSL cert uses?

Tags: tls, certificate, openssl, encoding, x509

How do I use the openssl x509 tool to see whether or not my strings are T61 or UTF8 encoded in the cert? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**openssl x509:** If you mean the Subject and/or Issuer field(s), the simplest and most readable way (IMO) is

```
openssl x509 -in certpemfile -noout -text -nameopt multiline,show_type
```

or if you want *only* the name field(s) change `-text` to `-subject` and/or `-issuer`. There are other formats, and if you want non-trivially encoded *data* to display usably you may need additional options; see the man page on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html) at "Name Options" about halfway down. If your input is what OpenSSL calls "DER" (binary) not the much more common "PEM" (textual), add `-inform der`.

If you mean extensions that can contain (Distinguished)Name fields -- I count SAN/IAN, NameConstraints, CRLDP, AIA/SIA, although I don't see how DN would be useful in the latter three, and there are surely more -- that's not supported that I know of. But see next.

**other:** `openssl asn1parse` dumps the exact types, lengths, and *mostly* values of any ASN.1 BER/DER structure, including a cert. For X.509-form extensions (wrapped in OCTET STRING) you can use `-strparse offset` to ASN.1-decode the nested structure. Identifying and selecting desired fields is your job and in general can be difficult, but since both DNs and extensions label each of their elements with a preceding OID (which OpenSSL calls just OBJECT) and `asn1parse` decodes all OIDs known to openssl (and you can give it additional ones) you can usually just visually scan for `countryName`, `commonName` and the like. **Note on PEM:** many `openssl` functions create or accept and ignore "comments" in PEM-format data, but `asn1parse` does NOT. It will handle the dash-BEGIN and dash-END lines, but almost anything else it will treat as part of the data causing wrong results. Verify your input file (or pipe or whatever) contains *only* the *one* cert.

Comment: Thanks, I can get different output now but how can I tell whether its in T61 or UTF8? The only difference in using the nameopt with the arguments now I get lines like countryName               = PRINTABLESTRING:ZA.

Comment: Can you give me an example ans1parse command I can use to view the dump of the cert?

Comment: You have typo in the `openssl` command name (missing `l`). I can't edit it as the minimum edit is 6 characters... maybe you as the author can edit it anyway.

Comment: @Marki555: thanks. yes, author can always edit, and so can users over some rep threshold but I don't remember exactly what. FWIW you could have reached the minimum edit by fixing the link, because the openssl.org website has been reorganized multiple times since 2015 when I wrote this answer :-(